# keep_prob in TensorFlow MNIST tutorial

Tags: tensorflow

I can't understand the following code in [the Deep MNIST for Experts tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#variables).

```
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
```

What is the purpose of **`keep_prob: 0.5`** when running `train_step`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `keep_prob` value is used to control the [dropout rate](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#dropout) used when training the neural network. Essentially, it means that each connection between layers (in this case between the last densely connected layer and the readout layer) will only be used with probability `0.5` when training. This reduces overfitting. For more information on the theory of dropout, you can see the original [paper by Srivastava et al](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ehinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf). To see how to use it in TensorFlow, see the documentation on the [`tf.nn.dropout()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout) operator.

The `keep_prob` value is fed in via a placeholder so that the same graph can be used for training (with `keep_prob = 0.5`) and evaluation (with `keep_prob = 1.0`). An alternative way to handle these cases is to build different graphs for training and evaluation: look at the use of dropout in the current [`convolutional.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7e3b8b23835ab0ac55d390aed2349af6e05dbe3b/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py#L216) model for an example.

Comment: @mrry I have one confusion, only be used with probability 0.5 when training, this line means it will keep 0.5 and above 0.5 and will ignore less than 0.5  or it means it will keep only ==0.5 ??

Comment: dropout rate link seems to be dead, could you update your answer?

Comment: @AadityaUra yes, it will only keep 50% of the units/neurons in that layer and drops the remaining ones. the ones that get to be dropped in each forward pass is completely random, you can even specify seed.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski, here you go: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout and keras version: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dropout?hl=en