# Tensorflow : What is actually tf.nn.dropout output_keep_prob?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, dropout

I am trying to understand concept of `output_keep_prob`:

So if my example is simple RNN :

```
    with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:
        cells = rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=500)
        cell = rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell=cells, output_keep_prob=0.5)

        model = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell, cell, inputs=embedding_lookup, sequence_length=sequence_le,
                                                dtype=tf.float32)
```

My confusion is if I am giving `output_keep_prob=0.5` what actually it means? I know that it makes less prone to overfitting (called regularizing) by adding a dropout. It  randomly turns off activations of neurons during training, ok I got this point but I am confused when I give

`output_keep_prob=0.5` and my no_of_nodes = 500 then 0.5 means it will randomly turn of 50% nodes at each iteration or it means it will keep only those connections which have more or equal probability of 0.5

```
keep_layers whose probability =>0.5
```

or

```
turn off 50% randomly nodes unit at each iteration ??
```

I tried to understand the concept by this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545798/keep-prob-in-tensorflow-mnist-tutorial) but there is also same confusion that what actually 0.5 means? it should drop 50% nodes at each iteration or keep only those nodes which have probability more or equal to 0.5

if the answer is second `keep only those nodes which have probability more or equal to 0.5` :

then it means suppose I have given 500 nodes units and only 30 nodes have 0.5 probability so it will turn of rest 470 nodes and will use only 30 nodes for incoming and outgoing connections?

Because  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107208/in-tf-nn-dropout-what-is-the-effect-of-keep-prob-argument) says :

> Suppose you have 10 units in the layer and set the keep_prob to 0.1,
>   Then the activation of 9 randomly chosen units out of 10 will be set
>   to 0, and the remaining one will be scaled by a factor of 10. I think
>   a more precise description is that you only keep the activation of 10
>   percent of the nodes.

While other side [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545798/keep-prob-in-tensorflow-mnist-tutorial) by @mrry says :

> it means that each connection between layers (in this case between the
>   last densely connected layer and the readout layer) will only be used
>   with probability 0.5 when training.

can anyone give a clear explanation which one is correct and what actually this value represent in keep_prob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Keep_prop` means the probability of any given neuron's output to be preserved (as opposed to dropped, that is zeroed out.) In other words, `keep_prob = 1 - drop_prob`.

The [`tf.nn.dropout()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout) description states that

> By default, each element is kept or dropped independently.

So if you think about it, if you have a large amount of neurons, like 10,000 in a layer, and the `keep_prob` is let's say, 0.3, then 3,000 is the expected value of the number of neurons kept. So it's more or less the same thing to say that a `keep_prob` of 0.3 means to keep the value of 3,000 randomly chosen ones of the 10,000 neurons. But not exactly, because the actual number might vary a bit from 3,000.

Scaling comes into the picture because if you drop a certain number of neurons, then the expected sum of the layer will be reduced. So the remaining ones are multiplied to feed forward the same magnitude of values as they would otherwise. This is especially important if you load a pretrained network and want to continue training but with a different `keep_prob` value now.

(Please note, you can decide to introduce non-independence into the drop probabilities with the `noise_shape` argument, please see the [`tf.nn.drouput()` description](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout), but that is outside of the scope of this question.)

The random decision to drop a neuron or not is recalculated for each invocation of the network, so you will have a different set of neurons dropped on every iteration. The idea behind dropout is that subsequent layers cannot overfit and learn to watch for arbitrary constellations of certain activations. You ruin the "secret plan of lazy neurons to overfit" by always changing which previous activations are available.

Comment: Thank you @Peter for that great answer , I have one more doubt so suppose my nodes are 10,000 and i have keep_prob 0.3 now it will kept 3000 neurons right ? now my confusion is this thing happen in each iteration ? if yes then in first iteration it takes randomly 3000 and then in second it will take another randomly 3000 or it takes static 3000 for each iteration ?

Comment: Recalculated for each iteration. Added a paragraph explaining this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive explanation for dropout efficiency might as follows.

Imagine that you have a team of workers and the overall goal is to learn how to erect a building. When each of the workers is overly specialized, if one gets sick or makes a mistake, the whole building will be severely affected. The solution proposed by “dropout” technique is to pick randomly every week some of the workers and send them to business trip. The hope is that the team overall still learns how to build the building and thus would be more resilient to noise or workers being on vacation.

Because of its simplicity and effectiveness, dropout is used today in various architectures, usually immediately after fully connected layers.

Generalization in machine learning refers to how well the concepts learned by the model apply to examples which were not seen during training. The goal of most machine learning models is to generalize well from the training data, in order to make good predictions in the future for unseen data. Overfitting happens when the models learns too well the details and the noise from training data, but it doesn’t generalize well, so the performance is poor for testing data. It is a very common problem when the dataset is too small compared with the number of model parameters that need to be learned. This problem is particularly acute in deep neural networks where is not uncommon to have millions of parameters.

Here is visual explanation i found :

[image]

[More info](https://chatbotslife.com/regularization-in-deep-learning-f649a45d6e0) here.